# Why is ( the better the job ) = the correct choice?

Tags: grammaticality, comparative-constructions, minor-sentences

Why is (  **the better the job** ) = the correct answer ?

The more I know, ....... I will get.

1. the better job
2. the better the job   ( the correct choice )
3. more job '

Link : https://www.grammar-quizzes.com/themore.html

Comment: I think the answers to this question might help you [the more the merrier - definite article used as an Adverb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60227/the-more-the-merrier-definite-article-used-as-an-adverb)

Comment: @ColleenV I don't think so, really. They are all about why or whether the word "the" is an adverb in the construction. They don't explain what it means or how it works ....

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but THE JOB seems more defensible than THE BETTER. We mean to say that the job will be better, so it seems relatively clear why we connect THE to JOB. I suppose that THE BETTER is like THE MORE, and like THE HARDER I work THE LUCKIER I get, articles that would be missing from the more natural word order: As I know more the job I get is better, and As I work harder, I get luckier. Perhaps we should look at the article-adjective pairs here as idiomatic in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the phrase "the better job" without a second "the" in between isn't grammatically correct & may make the sentence mean something different.

---

✔️ 1. "The more I know, the better **the job** *I will get*."

-> "The more I know, the better [that] **the job [that] I get** will be."

-> "Knowing more will get me ***a* better job**."

i.e. I am speaking *generally* about my chances of getting good jobs in the future, not about any specific jobs; the point of the sentence is "more knowledge = better job".

❌ 2. "The more I know, **the better job** I will get."

-> "The more I know, [then] *I will get* **the better job**."

-> Native speakers wouldn't construct a sentence like this, as the clause and implied conjunction are incompatible.

The implied conjunction "then" implies a binary cause and effect, while the clause "the more [that] I know" is more variable, implying a gradient of many possible outcomes; you can pair a binary with a binary, or a variable with a variable, but you can't pair a binary with a variable.

This sentence would also have a slightly different meaning, depending on whether you go with binary or with variable— "the" is a *definite* article, so the phrase "*the* better job" implies there are *exactly* two (2) *specific* jobs being discussed, one of which is better than the other, rather than an unknown or variable amount of *theoretical* jobs.

If you mean "knowing more = better [hypothetical] jobs", which is the meaning your quiz question is asking for, you use sentence #1.
If you mean "I will get the better *one* of two *specific* jobs", you could phrase it a number of ways, such as:

- "*If I know more*, I will get the better job."
- "*Knowing more* will get me the better job."
- "You get the better job *by knowing more*."

Et cetera.

❌ 3. "The more I know, **the more job** I will get."

-> This one is only incorrect because the word "job" is singular when it should be plural. This is because job/jobs is a **countable** noun, so you have to change what words you use for one (1) single *job* versus two (2) or more *jobs*.

-> Correct way to express this would be "The more I know, the more jobs I will get."

-> Conversely, words like "sand" and "water" are **uncountable** nouns, i.e. treated as a single mass, and thus treated as singular regardless of their size. "The more I travel, the *more sand* I will see" is right; "*more sands*" is wrong.
Singular elements of uncountable nouns are instead described with phrases like "grains *of* sand", "drops *of* water", etc.

---

Note that these differences are very subtle. In real life, people will probably understand what you mean even if you say it a little bit wrong, like #2 or #3. A quiz can be much stricter than normal conversation.

(source: native English speaker + studied basic linguistics)

Answer (score 0):

The more I know, the better job I will get.
This expression requires the article the before the adjective and the noun.

Information I add: (The) before ( better) is not used as a definite article but it is a part from the comparative structure.it means ( as or such ). ( the ) job = certain job I am qualified to get

The page gives extra explanation telling ( missing article )
[image]

I will get a better job the more I know. (basic word order)

The more I know, the better the job I will get. (fronted clause)

The more you know, the better the job. (reduced fronted clause)

This expression requires the article the before the adjective and the noun.

Comment: This doesn't really explain *why*. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Joachim 8  consider my answer = not a correct answer. You please answer it.  double comparative  ( the more ...the more ) >> The question is why we vote for the better the job and not ( the better job ) Many people think using (the) is redundant in the phrase ( the better the job) . I explained using ( the ) before the word job = specific job which I am qualified to

Comment: Thank you very much.  I got it